# Using Novocaine and AVCam together

Tags: ios, avcam, novocaine

My question is really simple. I want to record a movie using the [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) sample project from Apple. While recording, I'd like to filter the audio channel to extract a bunch of information I will use later (I found [Novocaine](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine)+[NVDSP](https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP) to be the best solution for me).
Now, I've seen that Novocaine and the AVCam don't work well together, eg. they both try to access the mic but just one of them can control it (the AVCam seems to "win" here).

Is it possible to let AVCam record the audio channel and in the mean time let Novocaine analyze that data in a separate process? AVCam should record the "real" sounds from the mic, while Novocaine elaborates them for a different purpose.

Comment: What does this mean? Why should I use two computers to handle realtime audio-video on an iOS device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've not been able to make these two components work together, I had to implement a custom movie recorder using `Novocaine` and [`GPUImage`](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) together. The first will record the audio session, while the latter will record the video session. After the recording has ended, I merge the two sessions together to obtain the final movie output.

It's a bit more complicated, but that's the only way I found to handle video and audio separately.